# Firefox sync about:config

Tags: firefox, sync

Does `Firefox` synchronize `about:config` preferences too?

If not, where is the config file located?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It synchronizes *some* settings – those that are enabled in `services.sync.prefs.setting`.

The user preferences are stored in `prefs.js` in your Firefox profile.

Answer (score 5):

Firefox synchronizes `about:config` settings for which there exists a `true` `boolean` entry called `services.sync.prefs.X`, where `X` is the setting name.

So if you wish to synchronize a new setting `X`, simply make a new `boolean` entry called `services.sync.prefs.X` and set it to `true`.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, the correct boolean entry to enable synchronization for entry `X` would be **services.sync.prefs.sync.X**; there are two **.sync**'s.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/Firefox_Sync/Syncing_custom_preferences.

Comment: Will the sync pref itself be synced as well?

Comment: The url has been moved to https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/sync-custom-preferences