# completely quit firefox when last tab is closed on mac

Tags: macos, firefox

I have the opposite problem of [Is it possible to leave Firefox open when closing its only tab?](https://superuser.com/questions/1309865/is-it-possible-to-leave-firefox-open-when-closing-its-only-tab)

Basically I am using firefox 100 on mac os, coming from windows and linux.
I also make use of the containers and of the extension [simple tab groups](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/simple-tab-groups/).

When firefox quits all of the opened tabs (and the ones hidden in the other groups) are saved and restored when restarted.

Unfortunately mac os has some "ideas" on when actually quit a running application.
I "learned" to just ignore the red button, as its behavior basically depends on the mood of the application developers that day.

But I really *need* to have a way to tell firefox/mac os that, when I close the last tab opened firefox must totally quit, not just "hide the ui", as, with current behavior, I just lose all the tabs in the other groups.

Comment: All Mac apps with multi-document capability behave like this. That's what Cmd/Q is for. Simply Quit & you'll get your windows back next launch. Close all windows first & you won't. By design.

Comment: Your "rule" has a lot of exceptions. Eclipse completely quits when you use the red button. Teams and Outlook no. iTerm is configurable. zooms quits. Firefox not. I can ignore the various behavior for all the other applications, but I use the browser 99% of the time.

Comment: Teams & Outlook are M$, all bets are off for them. Zoom doesn't quit when you close the window. iTerm I don't use. Eclipse looks like a java app not Mac-standard. For others, single window apps usually quit when you close the only window. Multi-window apps don't. Single window behaviour is relatively new, multi-window behaviour is as old as the Mac, or certainly since multi-tasking, early 90s.

Comment: Let me repeate: I don't care about the other apps actual behavior, apart from Firefox ATM. I also don't care about the "general rule". I was just showing you that it's basically up to the app developers to choose what will happen when you click on the red button. And all I care is to have a way to actually quit Firefox when the last tab Is closed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Mac OS X applications to close after last window closed](https://superuser.com/questions/53935/getting-mac-os-x-applications-to-close-after-last-window-closed)